# How to get the screen coordinates from the world coordinates in OpenGL android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am facing a situation in which I have to calculate the screen coordinates from a set of world coordinates. How can I do this in opengl android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the logic of [`gluProject()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluProject.xml), which is just a few matrix multiplies.

Comment: As a side note, the linked documentation misses to mention the perspective division step *v" /= v"(3)*, done after the *v" = P x M x v* step.

Comment: Hey I tried gluproject the results are quiyte strange...Here is my matrixes and veritces

Comment: float[] modelView = target.getViewMatrix();
        float[] projection = target.getProjectionMatrix();
        float[] modelViewprojectionarray = target.getModelViewProjectionMatrix();
        int[] view = {0,0,(int)screenWidth, (int)screenHeight};
        float x = screenWidth/2, y = screenHeight/2, z = 0.01f;
        float[] pos = new float[4];
        GLU.gluProject(x, y, z, modelView, 0,
                projection, 0,view, 0,
                pos, 0);
        float xmovedValue = convertPixelsToDp(pos[0],this);
        float ymovedValue = convertPixelsToDp(pos[1],this);